# Remove last TD before append to element in dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this piece of code where content is generated dynamically and it's executed each time a SELECT change it's value:

```
var htmlFabricanteBody = '',
    htmlSelFabricanteBody;

htmlFabricanteBody += '<tr data-idproductosolicitud="' + data.ent.idProductoSolicitud + '" data-id="' + data.ent.id + '">';
htmlFabricanteBody += '<td><input type="checkbox" name="fabLinkChoice[]" value="' + data.ent.idProductoSolicitud + '"></td>';
htmlFabricanteBody += '<td>' + data.ent.nombre + '</td>';
htmlFabricanteBody += '<td>' + data.ent.direccion + '</td>';
htmlFabricanteBody += '<td class="has_pais fabTd-' + data.ent.idProductoSolicitud + '"></td>';
htmlFabricanteBody += '<td>' + data.ent.telefono + '</td>';
htmlFabricanteBody += '<td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="modalAgregarPaises" data-fabricanteDistribuidorId="' + data.ent.id + '" data-productoSolicitudId="' + data.ent.idProductoSolicitud + '" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addPaisesFabricante" data-backdrop="static"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="' + Translator.trans('boton.editable_paises', {}, 'AppBundle') + '"></i></a></td>';
htmlFabricanteBody += '</tr>';

htmlSelFabricanteBody = '<tr data-idproductosolicitud="' + data.ent.idProductoSolicitud + '" data-id="' + data.ent.id + '">';
htmlSelFabricanteBody += '<td><input type="checkbox" name="fabLinkChoice[]" value="' + data.ent.idProductoSolicitud + '"></td>';
htmlSelFabricanteBody += '<td>' + data.ent.nombre + '</td>';
htmlSelFabricanteBody += '<td>' + data.ent.direccion + '</td>';
htmlSelFabricanteBody += '<td class="has_pais fabTd-' + data.ent.idProductoSolicitud + '"></td>';
htmlSelFabricanteBody += '<td>' + data.ent.telefono + '</td>';
htmlSelFabricanteBody += '</tr>';

$(htmlFabricanteBody).appendTo("#fabricanteBody");
$(htmlSelFabricanteBody).appendTo("#selFabricanteBody");
```

The only difference between `htmlFabricanteBody` and `htmlSelFabricanteBody` is this line:

```
htmlFabricanteBody += '<td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="modalAgregarPaises" data-fabricanteDistribuidorId="' + data.ent.id + '" data-productoSolicitudId="' + data.ent.idProductoSolicitud + '" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addPaisesFabricante" data-backdrop="static"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="' + Translator.trans('boton.editable_paises', {}, 'AppBundle') + '"></i></a></td>';
```

In order to avoid DRY, it's possible to remove the line above from `htmlFabricanteBody` before append to `#selFabricanteBody`? In other words `#fabricanteBody` should have the content of `htmlFabricanteBody` intact as it's, `#selFabricanteBody` should have the same content of `htmlFabricanteBody` minus the line I'm talking about, any advice? Workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can combine into a simple function that determines whether to add link or not. Seems a lot easier to read also since your variable names are very similar.

The other benefit is you can move the function out of the logic flow in your script and put it anywhere

```
function getRowHtml(data, showLink) {
    var row = '<tr data-idproductosolicitud="' + data.ent.idProductoSolicitud + '" data-id="' + data.ent.id + '">';
    row += '<td><input type="checkbox" name="fabLinkChoice[]" value="' + data.ent.idProductoSolicitud + '"></td>';
    row += '<td>' + data.ent.nombre + '</td>';
    row += '<td>' + data.ent.direccion + '</td>';
    row += '<td class="has_pais fabTd-' + data.ent.idProductoSolicitud + '"></td>';
    row += '<td>' + data.ent.telefono + '</td>';
    /* only variation */
    if (showLink) {
        row += '<td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="modalAgregarPaises" data-fabricanteDistribuidorId="' + data.ent.id + '" data-productoSolicitudId="' + data.ent.idProductoSolicitud + '" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addPaisesFabricante" data-backdrop="static"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="' + Translator.trans('boton.editable_paises', {}, 'AppBundle') + '"></i></a></td>';
    }
    row += '</tr>';    
    return row;
}

$(getRowHtml(data,true)).appendTo("#fabricanteBody");
$(getRowHtml(data,false)).appendTo("#selFabricanteBody");
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way, while maintaining your code structure, is this:

```
var htmlFabricanteBase = '<tr data-idproductosolicitud="' + data.ent.idProductoSolicitud + '" data-id="' + data.ent.id + '">';
htmlFabricanteBase += '<td><input type="checkbox" name="fabLinkChoice[]" value="' + data.ent.idProductoSolicitud + '"></td>';
htmlFabricanteBase += '<td>' + data.ent.nombre + '</td>';
htmlFabricanteBase += '<td>' + data.ent.direccion + '</td>';
htmlFabricanteBase += '<td class="has_pais fabTd-' + data.ent.idProductoSolicitud + '"></td>';
htmlFabricanteBase += '<td>' + data.ent.telefono + '</td>';

var htmlFabricanteBody = htmlSelFabricanteBody = htmlFabricanteBase;

htmlFabricanteBody += '<td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="modalAgregarPaises" data-fabricanteDistribuidorId="' + data.ent.id + '" data-productoSolicitudId="' + data.ent.idProductoSolicitud + '" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addPaisesFabricante" data-backdrop="static"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="' + Translator.trans('boton.editable_paises', {}, 'AppBundle') + '"></i></a></td>';
htmlFabricanteBody += '</tr>';

htmlSelFabricanteBody += '</tr>';

$(htmlFabricanteBody).appendTo("#fabricanteBody");
$(htmlSelFabricanteBody).appendTo("#selFabricanteBody");
```

However, a more elegant and powerful solution would be to leverage a templating language, like [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/). If you anticipate the complexity of this increasing, then a template language will become increasingly more useful.